# Django: How to filter for keyword in multiple fields on a model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have Article model with title and body fields. I'm building a search functionality and need to filter for articles that have keywords either in title or body fields.

I have two Articles. One has "candy" in the title and the other has "candy" in the body. So my result filter should have both articles. I'm trying below query but it's bringing me the first article only

```
Article.objects.filter(title__icontains='candy').filter(body__icontains='candy')
```

Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects.

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains='candy')|Q(body__icontains='candy'))
```

Comment: you could expand on this answer either by linking to the documentation, or explaining why and how this works (like why you are using `|`)

Comment: Yes, of course. Just updated the answer, you can follow the documentation about how [Q-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) work.